# Django Static Files Development

Tags: django, static-files

This seems to be a source of much confusion judging by the amount of similar titles on the subject, however trying everything I could find on static files with the django development server I've almost given up hope!

So my static files are served from *C:/Users/Dan/seminarWebsite/static/*, in which I have sub folders for images, css etc.

*SETTINGS:*

```
STATIC_ROOT = 'C:/Users/Dan/seminarWebsite/static/'  
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

The static files app is also active.

*URLS:*

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns  
urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

*TEMPLATE:*

```
"{{ STATIC_URL }}images/vision.jpeg"
```

However only a broken link appears and at this address: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/homepage/images/vision.jpeg` and I don't think it should be at that address (homepage is the url name of the page the static image file is being called to).

Comment: Appologies I accidently submitted without finishing the post! Will update now

Comment: @user1178602: I hope you will be able to update before it is being closed (only one vote left).

Comment: @user1178602: Nope, you didn't make it.

Comment: Once you've done that, you should flag this and ask for it to be reopened.

Comment: Looks like you don't have access to `{{STATIC_URL}}` in your templates. Have you added `'django.core.context_processors.static'` to [`TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#with-a-context-processor)?

Comment: I didn't but I have now thank you - didn't make a difference though

Comment: Thank you that was helpful! Something I'd overlooked. However the image still doesn't show.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

Based on what you've posted so far, it looks like you're following the docs for [`django.contrib.staticfiles`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#using-django-contrib-staticfiles). I agree that [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#using-django-contrib-staticfiles) can be difficult to follow especially if one is new to django.

I believe the confusion stems from the fact that `django.contrib.staticfiles` has **two** modes of operation:

1. During the development phase where the [development server](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-runserver) is used, it dynamically searches for static files in predefined directories and make it available on `STATIC_URL`
2. For deployment, it assists in collating static files to a single directory (defined using `STATIC_ROOT`) so that the static files can be hosted using a webserver suited for static files. This collation is done using `python ./manage.py collectstatic`.

Here's a quick summary of how to get up and running. I haven't had a chance to try it out so there may be mistakes. Hopefully this will help you get started and at the very least help you understand the docs. When in doubt, do refer to the docs.

### Hosting static files on the development server

1. Make sure you have `'django.contrib.staticfiles'` in `INSTALLED_APPS`
2. Specify [`STATIC_URL`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#static-url). This will be the path where your static files will be hosted on.

   ```
   STATIC_URL = '/static/'
   ```
3. Make sure your files are in the correct directories. By default, `staticfiles` will look for files within the `static/` directory of each installed app, as well as in directories defined in [`STATICFILES_DIRS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#staticfiles-dirs). (This behaviour depends on backends listed in [`STATICFILES_FINDERS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#staticfiles-finders)).
   In your case, you'd probably want to specify your directory in `STATICFILES_DIRS`:

   ```
   STATICFILES_DIRS = ( 
         'C:/Users/Dan/seminarWebsite/static/',  
   )
   ```
4. Make the view accessible by adding the following to the **end** of `urls.py`:

   ```
   from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
   urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
   ```
5. Make sure you have `DEBUG = True` in `settings.py`.

That's it.

If you run your dev server (`./manage.py runserver`), you should be able to access your file via `http://localhost:8000/static/images/vision.jpeg` (which serves `C:/Users/Dan/seminarWebsite/static/images/vision/jpeg`).

### Linking to static files in your templates

There are two ways to get a correct link for your static files - using the [staticfiles template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#with-a-template-tag), and making `STATIC_URL` accessible to your templates. Since you've attempted the latter, we'll stick to that.

1. Make sure you have `'django.core.context_processors.static'` in `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`. If you haven't redefined `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` then **there is nothing to do** since [it should be there by default](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#template-context-processors).
2. Make sure you use [RequestContext](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#django.template.RequestContext) when rendering your template. Example:

   ```
   from django.template import RequestContext
   # ...

   def some_view(request):
       # ...
       return render_to_response('my_template.html', {
           "foo" : "bar",  # other context 
       }, context_instance = RequestContext(request))
   ```

You should now be able to use the following in your `my_template.html`:

```
<a href="{{ STATIC_URL }}images/vision.jpeg" />
```

### Hosting static files on production server.

If all the static files you need to serve are store in that one directory (`C:/Users/Dan/seminarWebsite/static`), then you're almost there. Simple configure your webserver to host that directory on `/static/` (or whatever you set `STATIC_URL` to) and you're good to go.

If you have files scattered in different directories and/or app specific static files, then you'll need to collate them.

1. Set [`STATIC_ROOT`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-STATIC_ROOT) to the directory where you want to store the collated files.
2. Run [`./manage.py collectstatic`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#django-admin-collectstatic) to do the collation.
3. Configure your webserver to host the that directory (`STATIC_ROOT`) on `/static/` (or whatever you set `STATIC_URL` to).

Comment: I have that in my template context processors and thank you for pointing out my overlooking of requestcontext. However it still isn't working. What should the URL of the image be if it was working properly? As the image currently has the location http://127.0.0.1:8000/homepage/images/vision.jpeg which just seems wrong? Not that I'm an expert but that may shed some light on the the problem?

Comment: Also I found the docs quite difficult to follow from a novice perspective hence why I've been trawling various blogs/forums for advice

Comment: Can you see the image at `http://127.0.0.1:8000/homepage/static/images/vision.jpeg`?

Comment: No I get a 404 page not found error. Appreciate your help Shawn hopefully you can help me

Comment: Not sure if this is relevent but in my URL i put the 'urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()' line at the bottom of the file is that the correct place to put it? ie outside the URL pattern tuple?

Comment: @user1178602 I've added more details. Hopefully that will lead you down the right direction. Good luck.

Comment: If you use RequestContext in dev, do you need it in deployment scenarios? Do you have to rewrite everything once you deploy to not use RequestContext?  The Docs are very confusing at least to newbies like me, and I've read pretty closely.  I guess Django has gotten much more complex, b/c the docs used to be amazingly clear

Comment: Important bump: after doing all the steps for "Hosting static files on the development server" *restart your server!* I know it might be obvious to some of you, but I've spent a lot of time hopelessly moving my files from place to place until I tried restarting the server.

Comment: And also, for the steps regarding "Hosting static files on the development server", be sure that your app is listed in the "INSTALLED_APP" tuple in your settings.py !

Comment: Step 4 of "Hosting static files on the development server' section and steps 1 and 2 of "Linking to static files in your templates" section are not needed in Django 3.1. It'd be nice to update the answer with this info.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to share my reciept for a local development. It's similar to Shawn Chin's answer, *but not required `DEBUG=True` and special urlpatterns*, which is more universal and clean as I think.

Points 1, 2, 3 are the same as in the answer, but the following are different:

4. Serve URLs same way for all environments:

```py
# main urls.py

urlpatterns = (
    [
        # URLs from apps are here
        ...
    ]
    + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
)
```

*Relevant for Django 4.2*