# Django cannot find my static files

Tags: python, django, twitter-bootstrap, web, static

I am relatively new to web dev. and I am trying to build my first web application. I have my static folder in project_root/static but for some reason, I keep getting 404s when I run the server:

Not Found: /users/login/js/bootstrap.min.js
for example.

I have {% load staticfiles %} at the top of my html and in my settings.py I have:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))) 
STATIC_URL = '/static/'                                                                                        
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

Thanks.

---

EDIT: Fixed with a combination of the answers below. Thank you all!

Comment: Are you running the development server? Have a look at this answer -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9181047/django-static-files-development

Comment: What is your `STATICFILES_DIRS` setting?

Comment: So..... I just wanted to add a useless comment... I came here in search of help for the same issue... after screwing around with the file structure I originally had for some time... I finally got the page to refresh with all the resources... I hate to say that none of these answers truly helped... Just check to make sure that your file structure is correct - maybe look at @MohitRustagi 's answer.

Answer (score 6):

put your static js, css and other files in a directory called `static` inside your project directory then these settings will work:

```py
# this defines the url for static files
# eg: base-url.com/static/your-js-file.js
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# this is directory name where collectstatic files command will put your app level static files
STATIC_ROOT = 'staticfiles'

# this is directory paths where you have to put your project level static files
# you can put multiple folders here
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
)
```

based on these settings you will be able to access your static files correctly

Answer (score 2):

Go ahead and read this- http://agiliq.com/blog/2013/03/serving-static-files-in-django/

**Summary:** If "users" is the app name in your project, then create directory - 'users/static/js/'. and put bootstrap.min.js into js/. This file will be accessible at localhost:8000/static/js/bootstrap.min.js. Go ahead and try it out.

Answer (score 1):

Use below code in settings.py

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_ROOT = '/xxx/site/public/static/'
MEDIA_ROOT =  '/xxx/site/public/media/'
```

or
Delete or comment `DEBUG = True` in settings.py

Answer (score 0):

If `DEBUG=True` is settings.py it won't work. In such cases Django expects Apache/Nginx to take care of static files.