# Django static files in Development not working

Tags: python, django, django-staticfiles

I have the following directory structure in my project:

[image]

I'm trying to serve the static files in my environment, but I always getting the 404 error.

This is my settings.py configuration:

```
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

I also put this in my urls.py:

URLS:

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns  
urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

And this is my view:

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <!-- Tell the browser to be responsive to screen width -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <!-- Favicon icon -->
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="../assets/images/favicon.png">
    <title>Nossas Finanças</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="{% static 'plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
```

I've follow a lot of tutorials but I don't know what i'm doing wrong. I know by this question ([Django Static Files Development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9181047/django-static-files-development)) that the static files are served in two different way when is in Dev and in production.

Someone can help me?

Comment: where are you hosting your app? Also have you read about the `collect static`?

Comment: fire collectstatic command

Comment: I'm using default `runserver` from django, all this stuff are in my development environment

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/staticfiles/ AND https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/

Comment: Is "finances" in your installed apps ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "finances", "static")
```

Comment: What's the point of using `os.path.join()` if you hardcode a separator in a part of the path ??? This should be `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "finances", "static")`.

Comment: Yeah. did it. :)

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers, i think it will untill any changes in `STATICFILES_FINDERS`. Since both finders are different.

Comment: `AppDirectoriesFinder` is for finding `APPS`. Here `finances` is his project

Comment: Duh! I need another coffee obviously #facepalm

Answer (score 0):

For other people facing this problem *and* using Windows, keep in mind that you may need to restart the development server (the ".manage runserver" command) after having added new static files.