# Serving static files from the project directory in Django

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-staticfiles, django-static

I have the following project structure:

```
myproject
    - myapp
    - manage.py
    - myproject
          - settings.py
          - urls.py
          ...
    - static
    - templates
```

I want to serve all my static files from within this static folder. In my **settings.py**, I have the following:

```py
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

However, in one of my templates, when I call static files using the following...

```
{% load static %}
...
<link href="{% static 'css/styles.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" />
```

...nothing gets loaded.

However, if I add the css file within myapp/static/css/styles.css, then everything works properly. How can I serve static files from my project root folder? Thanks for any help.

Comment: I'm unsure I understand your question, because in the code example it looks like you're trying to load the file from myproject/static/css/styles.css and in the last paragraph you mention that adding the css file in the said location works. Did I understand that correctly and from where would you like to serve static files?

Comment: Can you share the following settings? `STATICFILES_DIRS`, `STATICFILES_FINDERS` and `STATIC_ROOT`

Comment: Are you working on a development server? There is an extensive explanation in this SO [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9181047/django-static-files-development)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**First Step:** Your project structure(folder directory) seems to be ok.

```
myproject
- myapp
- manage.py
- myproject
      - settings.py
      - urls.py
      ...
- static
- templates
```

**Second:** Need to define the `STATIC_URL = '/static/'` in **settings.py** file.

**Third:** Need to load the static in the template file and use the relative path.

```
{% load static %}
...
<link href="{% static 'css/styles.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Add this **settings.py** file.

```
# Add static file directory
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

Installed Apps listing  in **settings.py**  is supposed to exist in  the `django.contrib.staticfiles` in the list. if not then make sure its in the list.

Comment: This works for me, I also needed to serve static files from the root directory of my project. Just a tiny addition to above answer, make sure you import os package that is being used on the STATICFILES_DIRS tuple.

Answer (score 0):

You should add [STATICFILES_DIRS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#staticfiles-dirs) to `settings.py` as shown below to serve static files from Django project root directory:

```py
# "settings.py"

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [ # Here
    BASE_DIR / 'static/'
]
```