# Why the CSS of my Website is not appear by Django?

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, django

I created a Django backend Website then I designed a template for the frontend by HTML and CSS, but the CSS and Javascripts and some files like vendor of that dont not appear at final although I set address for CSS and Javascripts and vendor files for Login and Signup templates in settings.py and static and staticfiles.
you can see my codes in below images:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sg1lG.png)  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/buwmk.png) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWGA4.jpg) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OXHO1.jpg) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRza1.jpg)

I expect that the signup and login templates coming up with CSS  and JS files correctly.

Comment: Search before ask
[check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9181047/django-static-files-development)

Answer (score 1):

it was same with me, check this: setting DEBUG= True, python collectstatic, clearing cache, opening in incognito mode if the problem still exists copy your .css file into another new .css file in static folder, and then run collectstatic command.